# Module deployed at Azure IoTEdge Device does not receive Module Identity Twin changes

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-iot-hub

Module deployed at Azure IoTEdge Device does not receive module twin changes using `twin.on('properties.desired', function(delta){...});`.

It looks like that function was executed only once when module started and was not listening for twins changes after that (I was changing the module twin via Azure Portal).

I deployed sample module from [azure-iot-sdk-node](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/fd2da51a7b5818ffbfb3f74dae0fed13bb7a34fb/device/samples/simple_sample_module_twin.js).

My setup:

**iotedge version:** iotedge 1.0.6.1 (3fa6cbef8b7fc3c55a49a622735eb1021b8a5963)

**OS and version used:** Linux raspberrypi 4.14.98-v7+ #1200 SMP Tue Feb 12 20:27:48 GMT 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux

The same code works in IoT Edge Solution in Simulator without any issues.

Additional information is in [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/issues/509) I opened for Azure team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same code worked after reinstallation linux on RPi from scratch. It is strange that no errors were reported by device.